# Can I set up a separate RAID 5 devices?

Tags: windows-7, motherboard, raid

I have a GIGABYTE GA-P55M-UD2 motherboard in my system (Windows 7 64 bit) and currently have a Western Digital SATA 10k RPM drive in it.  Is it possible to add three more SATA drives to make a single RAID 5 device that is separate from the current 10k rpm drive?

Once I enable RAID for the SATA drives, am I required to make all of the drives part of the RAID volume?  Can I have separate RAID'ed and non-RAID'ed volumes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have non raid and raid volumes on the same system.

Once you enable raid, you can enter the raid manager for your motherboard when the system boots. You can then specify which disks (by disk ID) you wish to create the array on.